# Calculate Matrix addresses with limited land access

Tags: here-api

While using HERE's `Calculate Matrix` my team have encountered routes that are causing matrix calculations errors while using `balanced` routing mode.

Especially routes that are from Sweden to Great Britan.

```
 start: [
 { 
   id: 'sw', 
   latitude: 57.72994, 
   longitude: 11.94854 
 }
]
 destination: [
  { 
   id: 'gb', 
   latitude: 55.9007, 
   longitude: -3.64154 
 }
]
```

Example of sent request(provide your own appId and appCode):

```
https://matrix.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculatematrix.json?app_id=yourappid&app_code=yourappcode&mode=truck;balanced;traffic:disabled;tollroad:0&motorway:0&boatFerry:0&tunnel:0&dirtRoad:0&park:0&start0=geo!57.72994%2C11.94854&destination0=geo!55.9007%2C-3.64154&summaryAttributes=traveltime&costfactor&distance
```

Response:

```
{
  response: {
    metaInfo: {
      timestamp: "2019-08-06T07:53:21Z",
      mapVersion: "8.30.99.152",
      moduleVersion: "7.2.201930-4693",
      interfaceVersion: "2.6.66",
      availableMapVersion: ["8.30.99.152"]
},

   matrixEntry: [
   {  startIndex: 0,
      destinationIndex: 0,
      status: "failed"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Example with calculate route with no problem:

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_code=pxIXqdtgOSwQDXSDfjLQpw&app_id=cgZPrYfgRePXzXC3PbBp&jsonattributes=41&language=en-us&length=0&limitedweight=0&maneuverattributes=po,ti,pt,ac,di,fj,ix&metricsystem=metric&mode=balanced;truck;traffic:disabled&routeattributes=sh,gr&waypoint0=geo!stopOver!57.72994,11.94854&waypoint1=geo!stopOver!55.9007,-3.64154;;End&width=0
```

I would like to know what is the reason this is happening and what our team can improve to get results for such routes

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution, but I am currently encountering the same problem. It seems to originate from a select few address combinations. (see full response below; some start0 --> destination1 fails but destination1 --> start0 does not fail). I don't recall having encountered this problem before, while some of the locations currently throwing an error have been in my program before. Could it be something temporary?

```
{
    'response': {
        'metaInfo': {
            'timestamp': '2019-08-06T09:00:32Z',
            'mapVersion': '8.30.99.152',
            'moduleVersion': '7.2.201930-4693',
            'interfaceVersion': '2.6.66',
            'availableMapVersion': ['8.30.99.152']
        },
        'matrixEntry': [{
            'startIndex': 0,
            'destinationIndex': 0,
            'summary': {
                'distance': 50,
                'travelTime': 6,
                'costFactor': 6
            }
        }, {
            'startIndex': 0,
            'destinationIndex': 1,
            'status': 'failed'
        }, {
            'startIndex': 1,
            'destinationIndex': 0,
            'summary': {
                'distance': 2617,
                'travelTime': 327,
                'costFactor': 327
            }
        }, {
            'startIndex': 1,
            'destinationIndex': 1,
            'summary': {
                'distance': 48,
                'travelTime': 6,
                'costFactor': 6
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your GPS' starts and destinations?

Comment: Sure. For now, one location seems to cause many problems if it is the destination (not if it is the start). So far this seems to be the only location to have the problem.

For example:
start0 = 52.06835,5.10347 (problem location)
start1 = 52.12482,5.05344
start2 = 52.09298,5.10864

destination0 = 52.06835,5.10347 (problem location)

Going from destination0 to start1 or start2 does not give any problem.